# Resource Monitor Shows sqlserver.exe using c:\pagefile.sys

Tags: sql-server

I've got a SQL Server 2008 server that will frequently (multiple times throughout the day) reports

> "SQL Server has encountered 64357 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking
>   longer than 15 seconds to complete on file..."

.

I've noticed that in resource monitor when filtering to the sqlserver.exe process `c:\pagefile.sys` is showing up fairly often.

The server currently has 40MB of memory free and 260mb available. SQL Server is set to unlimited for ram and is using most of the 32GB on the server. It's a production server I've inherited where there isn't much downtime, so I haven't been able to change that.

I assume SQL is running out of memory and going to the page file?

Comment: Would recommend reviewing this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/glennberry/2009/10/29/suggested-max-memory-settings-for-sql-server-2005_2F00_2008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL Server has encountered 64357 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds

Does not indicate a memory problem.  It indicates a problem with the disks used to store your databases.

Comment: I thought that at first, but then thought perhaps if it's running out of memory and having to use the page file, that's drastically slowing down the response times...I could certainly be wrong though.

Comment: @Neostim You can use any tool to check your disk's health

Comment: A paging problem would be indicated by messages in the SQL Log like "A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 7215 seconds. Working set (KB): 7901284, committed (KB): 17040596, memory utilization: 46%."

Answer (score -1):

It seems so. Add more ram to the server and it will be fixed

Comment: Without limiting the ram usage, how does this solve the problem?

Comment: @JacobH Usually, don't limit the amount of memory used by dedicated production servers. If the server is paginating data to disk and you increase the memory available, then it won't need to swap data to disk. Limiting memory only make it worse.